# NOT getting number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given

Tags: php

I am not getting a php warning when doing this:

```
echo number_format('20.00', 2, '.', ',');
```

I would expect a warning message. php.ini error_reporting is E_ALL and errors as set to be displayed.

I am running php 5.6.6

Why am I not getting a warning?

Comment: because in PHP a string that holds numeric information is treated as though it is numeric type. Also numbers can be treated as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter expects number. Since php is a loosely typed language thats why it treats a number in a string as a number and that is why you are not getting any error.